# como ordenar un arreglo en forma ascendente y descendente?

Tags: javascript, array, ordenamiento

Buen día comunidad, estoy realizando un ejercicio en javaScript que me pide que en una función que recibe como parámetro un arreglo devuelva un objeto con dos arreglos el primero tendrá los números ordenados en forma ascendente y el otro en forma descendente. al momento tengo esto desarrollado:

```
    const numerosOrdeandos = (arreglo = undefined) =>{

    return console.log({
      ascendentes: arreglo.sort((a,b)=>a-b),
      descendentes: arreglo.sort((a,b)=>b-a),
    })
  }

  numerosOrdeandos([2,1,4,3,5]);
```

Me ordena los números correctamente pero en ambos arreglos lo hace de forma descendiente y no entiendo porque hace esto. Espero me puedan orientar gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `sort` no regresa un arreglo nuevo, sino que ordena el arreglo existente. Es decir, si tu tienes el arreglo `const arreglo =[2,1,4,3,5]`, y le haces `arreglo.sort()` no te va a estar creando otro arreglo, simplemente te va a estar ordenando el existente.

Al hacer en tu código 2 `sort` te va a regresar el `sort` más reciente.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una copia en cada uno, de la siguiente forma `[...arreglo]` lo que hará es que no ordenará el mismo arreglo dos veces, sino que primero creará una copia de ese arreglo y ordenará la copia

```js
 const numerosOrdeandos = (arreglo = undefined) =>{
    
  return console.log({
    ascendentes: [...arreglo].sort((a,b)=>a-b),
    descendentes: [...arreglo].sort((a,b)=>b-a),
  })
}

numerosOrdeandos([2,1,4,3,5]);
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución y explicación me quedo bastante claro cual era mi error y como era que lo tenia que solucionar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la función `sort` retorna una referencia al mismo arreglo. Por eso las propiedades `ascendentes` y `descendentes` tienen el mismo valor. Se puede resolver creando un nuevo arreglo `[...arreglo]`:

```js
const numerosOrdeandos = (arreglo) =>{
    return {
      ascendentes: arreglo.sort((a,b)=>a-b),
      descendentes: [...arreglo].sort((a,b)=>b-a),
    }
  }

 console.log(numerosOrdeandos([2,1,4,3,5]));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de gran utilidad tu solución y explicación.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el metodo .sort está mutando el array original.

Para evitar esto podrías hacer el sort sobre copias del array original, para ello hay varias opciones, una es con el uso de spread operators.

Quedaría algo así:

```js
   const numerosOrdeandos = (arreglo = undefined) =>{

    return console.log({
      ascendentes: [...arreglo].sort((a,b)=>a-b),
      descendentes: [...arreglo].sort((a,b)=>b-a),
    })
  }

  numerosOrdeandos([2,1,4,3,5]);
```

Aquí al usar `[]` se está creando un nuevo array, luego con `...arreglo` lo que se hace es agregar al nuevo array todos los valores de **arreglo**. Al ser un nuevo array este se guarda en una dirección de la memoria ram diferente, por lo que al tener una referencia diferente ya no afecta al array original.

Adjunto links a documentación de spread syntax.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp

---

Otra opción podría ser con el uso del método `.map`, ej:

```js
const numerosOrdeandos = (arreglo = undefined) => {
  return console.log({
    ascendentes: arreglo.map((item) => item).sort((a, b) => a - b),
    descendentes: arreglo.map((item) => item).sort((a, b) => b - a),
  });
};

numerosOrdeandos([2,1,4,3,5]);
```

Link a documentación **map**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Gracias por la solución y explicación muy bien explicadas y daré una leída a la documentación que me brindaste.

Comment: Agregué otra forma de lograrlo y link a su respectiva documentación. Me alegra que fuera de ayuda, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: probé la segunda solución y de igual manera funciona a la perfección, había pensado en usar el método map en un principio pero la verdad no supe muy bien como implementarlo ahora veo como era la forma de hacerlo nuevamente gracias.